# How to prevent `before_update` event from being fired upon deletion in SQLAchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a special validator for SQLAlchemy model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(length=16), default=u'')
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)

@listens_for(MyModel, 'before_update')
def complex_constraint(mapper, connection, target):
     # checks uniqueness of an instance using complex rule
     ....
```

When I try to delete an instance of `MyModel`, by some reason, SQLAlchemy calls `before_update` handler:

```
MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.name=='Dave').delete()
```

So my questions:

1. Why SQLAlchemy calls `before_update` handler when I try to delete an
   instance?
2. How to prevent this behaviour or workaround it? Any better
   solution than temporarily turning off events handling for this
   model?

Comment: You should post the `MyModel` class as well.

Comment: poosibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198252/sqlalchemy-before-update-called-instead-after-delete

Comment: @RedBaron added model example. Nothing special. No tree structures.

Comment: `filter(MyModel.name=='Dave')`, notice the `==`. My guess is `=` means assignment, so instance is marked as dirty and an update is fired.

Comment: @RedBaron sorry. my mistake with formatting an example. With `==` I see the same effect.

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys that reference this table?